# How to find shortest path if there are 3 possible values in the matrix?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, matrix, maze

I tried to find an algorithm for the following problem, but not able to get the complete solution.

In a matrix of size (100,100), each value can be --
*0 - Open, 1 - Blocked, 2 - Open with a gold coin*,

No. of gold coins can be between 0 to 10 in the matrix.

A is at start position (0,0) and B is at position (m,n) in the matrix.

The task is to find the shortest path A can follow to collect all gold coins and deliver them to B. A can move Noth, South, East or West.

Below is the code which I tried (maze is the matrix, B is the position of B)--

```
def democode(maze, B):
 #with some initialization over here 
  while len(queue) != 0:
    i,j=queue.pop(0)
    result+=1 
    for m,n in getneighbors(i,j):
        if (0<=m<rows) and (0<=n<cols):
            if m == B[0] and n == B[1]:
                break
            if maze[m][n] != 1 and visited[m][n] == 0:
                queue.append((m,n))
                visited[m][n] = 1

return result
```

This solution does not consider the issue of ensuring that A collect all the gold coins before reaching B. Need some suggestions on improving this code to cover all the scenarios.

Comment: Please provide a smaller example of your matrix!

Comment: Hope you are not looking for an efficient solution, since your problem is an instance of the [Traveling Salesman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

Comment: Please specify how many gold coins can be there in the matrix?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh , Example :- 
democode([[0,2,1],[1,2,0],[1,0,0]], (2,2)) , result = 4

Comment: @BishalGautam , no. of gold coins can be between 0 and 10

Comment: The easiest way would be to try all 10! possible orders of visiting the coins.  The shortest path between any two positions is easy to calculate.  (Some orders can probably be avoided with branch and bound, or metric inequalities, but I don't think the extra complexity is worth it here.)

Comment: You're welcome :)